# How to handle `tel:` protocol in electron app

Tags: electron, protocol-handler

I want to handle `tel:*` links in my electron application but I can't see my developing application in the list of opener apps after clicking this type of links.

```
protocol.handle('tel', (request) => {
    console.log(request); // not triggered and not showing my app to handle 
});
```

Any idea or working example would be appreciated.

OS: windows -
Electron version: 28.2.1